# mocking/stubbing a controller recaptcha method with rspec in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rspec

I'm just learning how to use stubs and mocks and I would like to mock out the below `verify_recaptcha` method to test both outcomes of the condition.

my controller code (DogMailsController)

```
      if verify_recaptcha(:model=>@email,:message=>"Verification code is wrong", :attribute=>"verification code")  
        if DogMail.make_mail dog_mail_params
          result = "success"
        else
          result = "fail"
        end
      else
        flash.delete(:recaptcha_error)
        flash.now[:error] = "Validation Failed. Please enter validation numbers/letters correctly at bottom."
        render :action => 'new', :locals => { :@email => DogMail.new(dog_mail_params)}
      end
     end
```

My spec so far

```
context "when master not signed in" do 
  context "when recaptcha verified" do 
    context "with valid params" do 
      it "should save the new dog mail in the database" do  

        expect{
          post :create, dog_mail: attributes_for(:dog_mail)
        }.to change(DogMail, :count).by(1)
      end
    end 
    context "with invalid params" do 
    end
  end
```

What should I put above expect inorder to stub/mock out verify_recaptcha? I tried `DogMailsController.stub(:verify_recaptcha).and_return(false)` but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to stub `controller.verify_recaptcha`, so with RSpec 3 syntax:

```
allow(controller).to receive(:verify_recaptcha).and_return(true)
```

Answer (score 2):

Recent versions (3.2+ I think) of the [Recaptcha](https://github.com/ambethia/recaptcha)  gem [hide the widget in test](https://github.com/ambethia/recaptcha/blob/v5.1.0/lib/recaptcha/configuration.rb#L43) by default, so you're more likely to end up needing to mock a Recaptcha failure than a Recaptcha success. If you're testing a Rails controller directly, you can use a variant of [infused's answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25356592/27358):

```rb
expect(controller).to receive(:verify_recaptcha).and_return(false)
```

If you're in a Rails 5 system or request spec, you may need to use `expect_any_instance_of`:

```rb
expect_any_instance_of(MyController).to receive(:verify_recaptcha).and_return(false)
```

You could also use

```rb
expect_any_instance_of(Recaptcha::Verify)
```

Note though that there are also situations (e.g. a server timeout) in which `verify_recaptcha` will raise `Recaptcha::RecaptchaError` instead of returning false, so you may want to test for those as well -- as above, but replace

```rb
and_return(false)
```

with

```rb
and_raise(Recaptcha::RecaptchaError)
```

(As it happens, this will also