# How do I bypass recaptcha verification in rails controller w/ RSPEC?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

In my rails `UsersController` - `users#sign_up` action, I perform verification to ensure the user has a valid recaptcha v3 token before moving on to the rest of the controller logic. If the recaptcha verification fails then the controller returns and responds with an error message. However, my `rspec` tests are failing because I am unsure how to mock / bypass the verification in the controller.

`spec/requests/auth_spec.rb:`

```
RSpec.describe "Authentication Requests", type: :request do
  context "sign up user" do
    it "fails to sign up a user without email address" do
      headers = { :CONTENT_TYPE => "application/json" }
      post "/api/v1/sign_up", :params => { :email => nil, :password => "password123"}.to_json, :headers => headers
      expect(response.header['Content-Type']).to include('application/json')
      expect(response_body_to_json).to eq({"error"=>"Failed to create user"})
    end
  end
end
```

The test is failing when I post to `/api/v1/sign_up` because there are missing params for the recaptcha token. As far as I understand, it isn't possible to mock a recaptcha v3 token. Therefore it would be preferable to have `verify_recaptcha` return `true` for the rspec test.

`controllers/api/v1/users_controller:`

```
def sign_up
  # Rspec fails here with missing params error
  return if !verify_recaptcha('sign_up', recaptcha_params[:token])

  @user = User.new(user_credential_params)

  if @user.valid?
    # Handle success/fail logic
  end
end

private

def user_credential_params
  params.permit(:email, :password)
end

def recaptcha_params
  params.permit(:token)
end
```

`controllers/concerns/users_helper.rb:`

```
def verify_recaptcha(recaptcha_action, token)
  secret_key = Rails.application.credentials.RECAPTCHA[:SECRET_KEY]

  uri = URI.parse("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=#{secret_key}&response=#{token}")
  response = Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)

  json = JSON.parse(response.body)

  recaptcha_valid = json['success'] && json['score'] > 0.5 && json['action'] == recaptcha_action

  if !recaptcha_valid
    render :json => { :error_msg => 'Authentication Failure' }, :status => :unauthorized
    return false
  end

  return true
end
```

Can I stub / mock the `verify_recaptcha` method that comes from the `users_helper` concern to return `true`? Is there a better way to accomplish this?

I did due diligence before asking this question and I found this post: [mocking/stubbing a controller recaptcha method with rspec in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25349927/mocking-stubbing-a-controller-recaptcha-method-with-rspec-in-rails).

This was the answer for that post:

`allow(controller).to receive(:verify_recaptcha).and_return(true)`

The above didnt work for me because individual had their `verify_recaptcha` method inside of `ApplicationController.rb` (which seems a little dirty in my opinion). Given that my `verify_recaptcha` method is inside of a concern, I am not sure how to access the concern via Rspec.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding `UserController.expects(:verify_recaptcha).returns(true)` to your test.
This will bypass the recaptcha or Just try finding where the verify_recaptcha method exists and then write controller or class name before the expect method in
`UserController.expects(:verify_recaptcha).returns(true)`